# Display enum with multiple properties in REST response when requesting XML

Tags: java, spring, enums

I'm working on writing a small REST web service using Java and Spring 5.0.1, and I'm having trouble displaying some error codes in the XML response. The class has a "code" and "message" property which I would like to display instead of the enum value, such as "USERNAME_EXISTS".

I'm using the [@JsonFormat](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) annotation to display the enum the way I'd like when the user requests Json, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to display the same way when requesting XML. The [@XmlEnumValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlEnumValue.html%20@XmlEnumValue) annotation seems close to what I need, but only takes one value.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to get this to display the way I'd like? I may also want to make the HttpStatus field behave the same way, so that it may display "409" and "Conflict" instead of just "CONFLICT".

When I request XML, Spring uses [Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html) to turn my object into XML. Do I need to write some java config and some custom [Marshaller](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html?is-external=true) implementations to get this to work?

Please let me know if I need to provide some more code samples.
Thanks a lot!

Here is my ErrorCode class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="error_code")
@XmlEnum
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum ErrorCode implements Serializable
{
    USERNAME_EXISTS("1001", "The specified username already exists."),
    EMAIL_IN_USE("1002", "The specified email address is already in use.");

    private String code;
    private String message;

    private ErrorCode(String code, String message)
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="code")
    public String getCode() 
    {
        return code;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="message")
    public String getMessage() 
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

When I request Json, the enum is displayed the way I would like.

```
{
    "httpStatus": "CONFLICT",
    "errorMessages": [
        {
            "errorCode": {
                "code": "1001",
                "message": "The specified username already exists."
            },
            "developerMessage": "User could not be created due to a conflict."
        }
    ]
}
```

But requesting XML does not display the enum code and value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error_response>
    <error_messages>
        <developer_message>User could not be created due to a conflict.</developer_message>
        <error_code>USERNAME_EXISTS</error_code>
    </error_messages>
    <http_status>CONFLICT</http_status>
</error_response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAXB will only marshal `enum` classes as `enumeration` XML types.

To override that, you need to supply an [`XmlAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) using the [`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html) annotation. It needs to convert the `enum` type to a normal `class` type, which is then annotated as needed.

Here is one way to do it for your example, with the `XmlAdapter` and the `class` type as static nested types of the `enum`, to keep it all together.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ErrorCode.Xml.Adapter.class)
enum ErrorCode {
    USERNAME_EXISTS("1001", "The specified username already exists."),
    EMAIL_IN_USE("1002", "The specified email address is already in use.");

    private final String code;
    private final String message;
    private ErrorCode(String code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return this.code;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(propOrder = {"code", "message"})
    static final class Xml {
        private String code;
        private String message;
        Xml(ErrorCode v) {
            this.code = v.getCode();
            this.message = v.getMessage();
        }

        static final class Adapter extends XmlAdapter<Xml, ErrorCode> {
            @Override
            public Xml marshal(ErrorCode v) throws Exception {
                return new Xml(v);
            }
            @Override
            public ErrorCode unmarshal(Xml v) throws Exception {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class XmlTest {
    private ErrorCode errorCode;
    public XmlTest() {
    }
    public XmlTest(ErrorCode errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XmlTest.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(new XmlTest(ErrorCode.EMAIL_IN_USE), System.out);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xmlTest>
    <errorCode>
        <code>1002</code>
        <message>The specified email address is already in use.</message>
    </errorCode>
</xmlTest>
```

Comment: This looks like it should do the trick! Thanks very much! I'll be back if I have any questions.